# How to access and manipulate structural directives during an e2e test

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, angular2-directives, e2e-testing

**Background:** I want to be able to permutate all possible configurations of an Angular2 screen for a given route and screenshot them using Protractor: http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging.

**Issue**: I can't seem to find a way to acces a directive (like ng-if for example) during an e2e Test.

- Is it possible to access the ng-if directive inside of an e2e test?

  - If yes: is there a way to manipulate the directive? By manipulate i mean to influence the evaluation of the directive without changing the input on which the directive depends.

**Possible solution path**: here is an example on how i acces the router to be able to navigate to a specific route:

```
it('should get the router', () => {
browser.executeScript(() => {
  const ng = window['ng'];
  const root = document.getElementsByTagName('app-root')[0];
  const router = ng.probe(root)
    .injector.get(ng.coreTokens.Router);
  const routes = router.config;
  ...
  ...
  return [];
}).then(ret=> console.log(ret));
});
```

**Thoughts**:

- Maybe it is possible to somehow get the ng-if directives using ng.probe

I would apreciate any hints regarding my question.

Comment: Do you want to get all `ngIf` directives on page?

Comment: Check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/4TU2iIZmZf410fa09gtW?p=preview (look at index.html)

Comment: I want to be able to acces all the structural directives on a page, so i tought ngIf would be a good start. Your plunker looks promising, il take a closer look at it and try to adapt it for my e2e test. After that il give you feedback. Thx for the post

Comment: @yurzui, your solution is what i have been searching for. If you post it as a solution i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

html

```
<button id="find">Find ngIf directives and show all</button>
```

script

```
var findComments = function(el) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType === 8) {
            arr.push(node);
        } else {
            arr.push.apply(arr, findComments(node));
        }
    }
    return arr;
};


function findNgIfDirectives() {
  var commentNodes = findComments(document);
  const ng = window['ng'];
  commentNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    var debugNode = ng.probe(node);
    var ngIf = (debugNode.providerTokens[0]);
    var ngIfInstance = debugNode.injector.get(ngIf);

    ngIfInstance.ngIf = true;
  });

}
document.getElementById('find').addEventListener('click', findNgIfDirectives)
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4TU2iIZmZf410fa09gtW?p=preview)**